# Reading huge files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I have to read a large files 4-10gb each line by line, the problem is that a .Net process gets and OutOfMemory exception when I read ~2gb

At first I am just attempting to count the lines, however I will need to access each line individually to strip some data from it.

From what I can see, every option keeps the previous lines in memory, where I only want it to keep the currently read line(unless anyone knows a trick to keep all of it)

Here is that I tried, and several things like it:

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(FilePath);
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)    //This is where it errors
{
   count++;
}
reader.Close();
```

The exception is:

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32 minBlockCharCount)
at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char* value, Int32 valueCount)
at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char[] value, Int32 startIndex, Int32  charCount)
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
at CSV.Program.NumLines() in C:\Users\ted\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\vConnect\CSV\CSV\Program.cs:line 100
 at CSV.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\ted\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\vConnect\CSV\CSV\Program.cs:line 20
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Thanks

Comment: No, if each line is a reasonable length it should be absolutely fine, assuming you're not actually keeping the data yourself. You shouldn't need to call `DiscardBufferedData`. What is your *real* code doing with the data after stripping something from it?

Comment: Please post the *full* exception including it's call stack and the actual code where it occurs. There is no need to discard the buffered data. It's *not* the buffer that causes problems but how you handle the strings you read.

Comment: I don't think that `DiscardBufferedData` does what you think it does. It's only used to resynchronize the Reader and the underlying stream.   Have you tried this without that extra method call?

Comment: Generating a new file from data striped out. The data is an CSV style export of a database, and is not always the same size

Comment: The buffer is *only* a 1KB buffer ([source here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/System/io/streamreader.cs,48)) that is used to speed up loading bytes from disk. Cleaning it just makes your code slower. Post the full exception and the code where it occurs.

Comment: Should I guess that there are no newlines in the text?

Comment: Looks like a line ending problem - unix vs windows? Try `flip`.

Comment: What's the value of `count` when the exception is thrown ?

Comment: It is *technically* possible, happens when the file is corrupted and no longer contains text.  Nothing but binary zeros for example.  Squarely falls in the "crap happens" category, the kind you should never code for since you still won't get any usable data out of that file.

Comment: Count is equal to 368587 when its thrown

Comment: From the [source of StringBuilder](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,1969) it's apparent that the exception is thrown when the buffer has to read *more* than its maximum capacity. This capacity though is [Int32.MaxValue by default](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,139). Most likely this is a line ending problem

Comment: Its not a line ending problem as it reads 368587 lines first

Comment: Isn't simply StringBuilder consuming the memory?

Comment: Yes Filburt, that is the issue, however... I don't care about all the "old" lines... only the current one

Comment: There must be something missing here. Because you code is fine and if you are 100% sure about your EOL this should work.

Comment: Its just that the file is to long for StringBuilder to hold

Comment: To be totally certain and just for the heck of it, I tested reading a file line by line with a 26 GiB text file, with line lengths skyrocketing up starting at 20 and ending somewhere in the 21 million character range, and memory was very stable at ~30-60 MiB for the entire duration. The `ReadLine` code is definitely not a problem.

Comment: It defiantly is... because I just use Flints answer and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use methods from the class FileStream: [FileStream.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) and FileStream.Seek should allow you to do what you need. An example can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/543821/ReadplusBytesplusfromplusLargeplusBinaryplusfilepl

You'll have to modify that slightly but essentially you can start at 0, read until you find a newline character, process the line, start from where you got to and repeat. It won't be terribly efficient but it will get the job done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah your correct, which a few modifications I can read line by line.

Comment: All you'd be doing is trying to reinvent the wheel. `StreamReader` already does this, quite well in fact. The chance that you'll screw up your replacement code for `StreamReader` is very high. (For binary files, you shouldn't use `StreamReader` obviously)

Comment: Agreed, in an ideal world you would use a StreamReader. Unfortunately, for whatever reason, that's not working here... For something as simple as reading line by line I'm not sure the risk of "screwing up" something would be high enough to deter me from using this solution, personally, but others may have different opinions.